# Inserting array into mySQL row

Tags: mysql, express

I am new to mySQL. I get an error when I try to call this function that create user data into mySQL database.

```
export async function createUser(firstName, lastName, username, password, roles) {
    const [result] = await db.query(`
       INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, username, password, roles)
       VALUES (? , ?, ?, ?, ?)
    `, [firstName, lastName, username, password, roles])
    const id = result.insertId;

    return getUser(id);
}
```

```
router.post("/create-user", async (req, res) =\> {
const {firstName, lastName, username, password, roles} = req.body;
const user = await createUser(firstName, lastName, username, password, roles);
res.status(201).send(user);
});
```

I got `error: Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` when the api is hit. I know the problem lies in the roles as it is an array and the datatype was set to JSON in mySQL but I somehow couldn't find the answer to this.

Thank you for your help.

I try to create a user but got an error = error: Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution right when I posted this.

```
    export async function createUser(firstName, lastName, username, password, roles) {
    const [result] = await db.query(`
       INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, username, password, roles)
       VALUES (? , ?, ?, ?, ?)
    `, [firstName, lastName, username, password, JSON.stringify(roles)])
    const id = result.insertId;

    return getUser(id);
}
```

JSOn stringify the array seems to do the trick.